# How do I view the DDNS leases from BIND9 and DHCP server?

Tags: networking, dns, bind, bind9

**How do I view the DDNS leases from BIND9 and DHCP server?**

I have set up isc-dhcp-server updating leases with a fixed IP address from `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` to BIND9 zone and reverse zone.

This command only shows the dynamic leases:

```
dhcp-lease-list --lease /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
```

I want to show all the leases. Is there a way, like viewing the zone records?